# Solve for x: $\frac{a_1}{x^{-a_1}-1} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{x^{-a_n}-1} = b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to solve this equation for $x$ :

\begin{equation}
\frac{a_1}{x^{-a_1}-1} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{x^{-a_n}-1} = b
\end{equation}
where $b$ and $a_i$'s are positive integers.

I'm not sure whether it is possible to solve this equation. Any hints or tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally not possible, other than numerically.

Comment: Thanks, @GerryMyerson, for your answer. I also thought that it is not possible to solve the equation analytically. Now I will use a numerical approach.